# Uniform smoothness in $L^p$ via Hanner's inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Exercise 5 in chapter 2 of Lieb and Loss's *Analysis* asks the reader to show that Hanner's inequality,

$$\|f+g\|_p^p + \|f-g\|_p^p \ge (\| f\|_p + \|g \|_p )^p + |\| f\|_p - \|g \|_p |^p,$$

which is valid in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for $1\le p \le 2$, "shows that the unit sphere is 'uniformly smooth', i.e., it has no corners."

I wasn't sure what this statement meant, so I looked up the definition in the Banach space literature and found a few equivalent ones, along with proofs of much more general statements that implied this one. However, I can't figure out what Lieb and Loss are getting at. None of the proofs I found seem appropriate for a textbook exercise, because they go through several intermediate characterizations of uniform smoothness.

Is there a way to interpret this claim so that it has a relatively immediate proof from Hanner's inequality?

Comment: It would not be $\|f\|_p$ and $\|g\|_p$ instead of $\|f_p\|$ and $\|g_p\|$?

Comment: @MathOverview Thanks for pointing that out! I fixed it.